# JavaScript: setInterval and clearInterval, which way is correct?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

Which way is correct and more efficient in using setInterval() and clearInterval()?

1.

```
something = setInterval(function() {
    try {
        ...load something
        clearInterval(something);
    } catch (e) {
      // error
    }
}, 5000);
```

2.

```
 something = setInterval(function() {
    try {
        ...load something            
    } catch (e) {
      // error
    }
}, 5000);

setTimeout(something, 7000);
```

EDIT:

For #2, I meant setTimeout() instead of clearInterval().Has been changed.

Comment: You refer to the handler with the (global) variable `something`, but you reference it with `interval`.

Comment: Depends on what you are doing. #2 is certainly not correct. You are clearing the interval before it even has a chance to run. #1 might be correct, but since you are clearing the interval the first time it runs, you should probably use `setTimeout` instead.

Comment: `clearInterval(something);` It will work in both scenario. Additionally  `clearInterval` accepts only single parameter. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval

Comment: `clearInterval` function only takes 1 parameter (the interval ID, returned by `setInterval`). Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Comment: You are correct, interval was meant to be something. A typo.

Comment: `setTimeout` only takes functions and strings as arguments. in #2 you provide it an interval handle which is a number (which does nothing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the `interval` you're passing into `clearInterval` is meant to be `something`.

Your second example will never fire your timer, because you clear the timer immediately after setting it. You're also passing an argument (`7000`) into `clearInterval` that won't get used ([`clearInterval`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#dom-windowtimers-clearinterval) only accepts one argument).

Your first example is right **provided** that you want to clear the repeated timer at the point where you're calling `clearInterval` from within the handler. Presumably that's in an `if` or similar, because if you want a one-off timed callback you'd use [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout), not `setInterval`.

---

> EDIT:
>
> For #2, I meant setTimeout() instead of clearInterval().Has been changed.

That completely changes the question. No, that's not correct. `setInterval` schedules the function to be called repeatedly on the interval you give it, you don't pass its return value into `setTimeout`.

Comment: You are correct, interval was meant to be something. A typo. It has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something to happen over and over again you use `setInterval` if you only need it to happen once use `setTimeout` (you can simulate `setInterval` by chaining multiple timeouts one after the other). Timeouts only happen once therefore you do no need to clear them. Also `clearInterval` does not take a time argument so the interval you set will be cleared before it ever executes since classic javascript is synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

just to complete the answer, take many care with setInterval(). if your "...load something"  take sometime more time to load than the time according (for a reason or another). it will just don't do it for this time and will wait the next call of setinterval.
I encourage to use setTimeout() as much as possible instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can find find below the use cases that are, according to me, aswering to your questions:

For your case 1:

```
var something = setInterval(function() {
    // Do stuff, and determine whether to stop or not

    if (stopCondition) {
        clearInterval(something);
    }
}, 5000);
```

For your case 2:

```
var something = setInterval(function() {
    // Do stuff
}, 5000);

// Pass a function to setTimeout
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(something);
}, 17000);
```